# Uploading Assets w/ Immediate Save?

Tags: entries, assets

Heyo - I have an entry form in which you select/upload assets (photos). The asset has a caption/copyright (custom)field attached to it, so ideally I'd tell them…

1. Click "Add Asset" and upload/select your photos
2. When the pills show up in the entry form, double-click them to add captions/copyright

But, I find that if you do the above, you won't see the caption/copyright field (just title and file name) *unless* you save the entry between steps one and two.

[image: Before saving…]

[image: After saving…]

I can see why this could be … the images are probably in a holding position until you save the entry(?). But just wondering if someone can confirm I'm not mucking something up, or maybe has a workaround?

It seems weird to have a note on the entry form that says "Reminder: 'Save and Continue Editing' to add captions to the images.

Same issue also comes up when you need to upload assets in a field, then in a subsequent field choose one of the assets (say, an entry form where you upload a group of images, then want to select one of the images to be the group's thumbnail).

Any ideas? Tks in advance.

Comment: Just tested it, but I can't confirm that behavior, alsophil. I see the fields straight away after upload (via form or drag and drop).

Comment: Hmn. I wonder if this has to do with using {slug} in the default upload location? My hope was to base asset folder names on entry slugs to make housekeeping is a bit easier, but I can see where that might be causing problems. Off to test…

Comment: Yep, the problem was dynamically generating the asset path using {slug}. I feel foolish for not checking that sooner.

Comment: Hey @alsophil, welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange! I resurrected your question and would encourage you to provide and accept your answer so your troubleshooting might help someone else. You did some great work here, so it'd be a shame to see it disappear.

Answer (score 3):

So, thanks to @carlcs for verifying it was my setup…

turns out I had set the asset's Default Upload Location to include the slug (i.e. /photography/{slug}) and restricted uploads to that folder. This way images would end up in a folder whose name matched the entry slug, making it easier to clean out unused assets from time-to-time.

But that approach was the source of the problem. Once I removed {slug} from the default upload location it all worked as expected, the caption field appeared immediately after adding the asset.

Of course, in retrospect this makes total sense — there's no {slug} until you save the entry.